# Upgrading From Vista to windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, installation

Will we get same performance of a fresh windows 7 installation by upgrading vista to windows 7.

Comment: The question is kinda vague. What performance do you care about? Boot time? Start menu response speed? App load times? Search speed? ETC ETC ETC. If you enumerate what's important to you, then it will become easier to measure perf changes, and the question will become easy to answer.

Comment: I am asking abt overall performance ( booting, app load,response time etc)

Answer (score 3):

You'll never get the same performance from an upgrade as you would get from a fresh install. That being said though, from what we've seen so far with Windows 7, there will be a performance increase in 7 over Vista.

Comment: I know this is a common idea, and I don't disagree, but is there any particular reason we can point to when somebody makes this claim?

Answer (score 3):

Where possible, do a Clean Install.
If you're worred about files / settings - use the Files and Settings Migration Wizard.
It does a fantastic job of backing up all the settings; then on the new install, run the same wizard, and point it to the file.
I've not tried Vista Backup => Win7 Restore, but I'd say there's a good chance it will work.

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 3):

I tried it and didn't see any performance difference between the fresh install and the upgrade on the same hardware with the same apps on 3 different systems (2 laptops, 1 desktop) so we'll be upgrading, however I'd still generally agree with Matt.

Answer (score 1):

You should do a clean install of Windows7, you applications and data, unless you have applications installed that you cannot reinstall. This will result in a smaller Windows installation that will consume less disk space.

Answer (score 1):

Extreme tech just did a series on the different options for upgrading from vista or xp to win7.  Basically, their findings were that doing an upgrade install was ok from vista, but there was a lot of performance issues in the system, and recommended just doing a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how clean the Windows Vista installation is and what you would install on the Windows 7 installation. So, if you are really going for performance then you would have to do a clean install. If you don't want to go trough all the hassle an upgrade would be better, unless your coming from a very slow Windows Vista installation. One thing is sure, Windows 7 is faster than Windows Vista. ;-)